# Newbie: MVC3 authentication / remember me

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC, so this question may be trivial.
In my LogOn action, I do the following:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(UserModel userModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        ActionResult retvalue = null;
        UserProfile user = MyDatabaseAccess.Instance.GetAuthenticatedUser(userModel.EmailAddress, userModel.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userModel.EmailAddress, userModel.RememberMe);
            Session["LoggedOnUser"] = user;
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                retvalue = Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                retvalue = RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            retvalue = RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }
        return retvalue;
    }
```

At this point my session has the full UserProfile object and I use it throught the website, so far things are working correctly.

Next time the user hit the website the user is already Authenticated (rememberme was set to true), and the User.Identity.Name has the email address of the user that was authenticated previously which is correct.
The problem is that I would like to load UserProfile into the session the same way I do it in the LogOn action.
I want a single place where I do that, rather than in every [Authorized] action.

Is there such way ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to store this information in the session.  The reason is that the session cookie is far more vulnerable than the authentication cookie.  Session also has problems like you're experiencing.  Also remember that a session can go away at any time.  It can expire, or the worker process can recycle, or several other reasons, but the end result is that the session will just disappear on you.  Plus session is more difficult to scale to a server farm approach.  It's not a good idea to store any state there, and if you do it should be short term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to create a SecurityContext through which you access the user information. You could then keep your SecurityContext in the session. If the user is authenticated, but the SecurityContext doesn't exist in the session, you read the data from Db and add it to the session again.

Something like this perhaps:

```
public static class SecurityContext
{
    public static UserProfile CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as UserProfile;

            if (user == null)
            {
                using (var ctx = new YourDbContext())
                {
                    user = ctx.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == 
                               HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = user;
                }
            }

            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

At any point in your application you could then access your user profile by calling `SecurityContext.CurrentUser`

You would of course still have to use the `[Authorized]` attribute on your controller/actions to make sure that the user is authenticated. The SecurityContext is just a wrapper to make it easier to access information about the authenticated user.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example or an article please ?

Comment: This is a common way to do this, but I consider it a serious hack.  A better solution is a custom IIdentity and IPrincipal.

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson: I do not have access to User.Identity at that point, unless its inside one of my Actions. how do you go around that ?

Comment: @Pacman I believe `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` should be available outside your controllers as well.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is by implementing a custom IIdentity and/or IPrincipal.  You would store the frequently used information in the Authentication cookie.  If the information is not sensitive (ie you just use it to display the users name and not used for anything security related) then you can just store it in your own cookie.

There's a good article here:

http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0